# Futuristic "Govt + Army against rebels" movie with a female central character

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie in 1999 or 2000 on TV (when they wouldn't even display names during the movie). It was a futuristic "Govt + Army against *rebels*" kind of a movie with a female central character. I remember 4 things from the movie:

1. The movie wasn't animated but lots of animated scenes were shown in between like *Natural Born Killers*!
2. Lots of fancy airships and guns.
3. The girl when captured refers to blowjob as "Anyone needs an oil change"
4. In the final fight scene, an animation is shown where her boobs turn into missiles.

Looked like a hell of a movie but I have never been able to track it! Would appreciate if anyone can help!

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged.  You've posted this exact same question here and on Movies and TV.  It really should be posted to only one site, not both.

Comment: yes! I am guilty of that but both forums seem appropriate for the question and answer could come from any one :$

Comment: If your question is more appropriate to one site rather than another, moderators will move it.  Please do not crosspost.

Comment: The cross-post can be found [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/can-anyone-help-me-identify-this-sci-fi-movie).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds a bit like [Tank Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114614/), though I don't remember the "oil change" bit off the top of my head.

[image]

Comment: Definitely a *"so bad its good"* movie. I'm told that people who know the source material don't like even on that level.

Comment: How can any movie with Ice-T as a mutant kangaroo and Iggy Pop as a pedophile possibly be *bad*?

Comment: The oil change bit is after they initially capture her and their on the plane.

Comment: @phantom42 Also Malcolm McDowell being Evil, which is what he does best.  Nonetheless, it did still manage to end up in the "so bad it's bad" camp, at least for me, despite brief moments of sublime genius.

Comment: Didn't really fulfill the promise of the comic.